# querying firebase data among all children with auth

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

I followed [this](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/12/syncing-data-firebase-using-ionic-framework/) tutorial to make an app with firebase sync and  authentication. But now, I don't know how to make a query to search among all children because these children have a lexicographical-based key.

To be more specific, from this example, how do you query all "currentCity" from all "users"

```
{
  "users" : {
    "1e2f048f-a3a0-4190-afad-81d724ed1997" : {
      "currentCity" : "Arrecifes",
      "currentCountry" : "ARG",
      "currentState" : "BSA",
      "day" : {
        "domingo" : true,
        "jueves" : true,
        "martes" : false,
        "miercoles" : true
      },
      "gender" : "Masculino",
      "name" : "Guillermo H Acosta",
      "position" : "Medio",
      "registered" : true,
      "timeSince" : "22:00",
      "timeUntil" : "23:00",
      "whereToPlay" : "Güemes"
    },
    "39c6ccf9-61ec-446e-9af3-3a87810fab71" : {
      "currentCity" : "Alvear",
      "currentCountry" : "ARG",
      "currentState" : "CRR",
      "day" : {
        "jueves" : true,
        "miercoles" : true,
        "viernes" : true
      },
      "gender" : "Masculino",
      "name" : "Guillermo Acosta",
      "registered" : true,
      "timeSince" : "21:00",
      "timeUntil" : "23:00"
    },
    "4991bdc9-dfc4-4ff5-ab81-0e28f1b3ab53" : {
      "currentCity" : "Cordoba",
      "currentCountry" : "ARG",
      "currentState" : "COR",
      "day" : {
        "miercoles" : true,
        "viernes" : true
      },
      "gender" : "Masculino",
      "name" : "Hsjja",
      "timeSince" : "02:00",
      "timeUntil" : "03:00"
    },
    "509364fd-388b-42ff-91ed-0811811a4ff3" : {
      "day" : {
        "jueves" : true,
        "lunes" : true,
        "martes" : false,
        "sabado" : true
      },
      "name" : "Guillermo Acosta",
      "position" : "Delantero",
      "timeSince" : "13:00",
      "timeUntil" : "14:00",
      "whereToPlay" : "Güemes"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @FrankvanPuffelen now it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Firebase Database, you either get a node or you don't get that node. There is no way to get a part of each nodes in a query.

So if you want load just the cities of all users, you should keep a node that contains just that information:

```
{
  "userCurrentCities" : {
    "1e2f048f-a3a0-4190-afad-81d724ed1997" : "Arrecifes",
    "39c6ccf9-61ec-446e-9af3-3a87810fab71" : "Alvear",
    "4991bdc9-dfc4-4ff5-ab81-0e28f1b3ab53" : "Cordoba",
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I'll keep that in mind. So instead of create a node for each user I have to create nodes for each attribute which I need filter into my app? am I right?

Comment: In general when using a NoSQL database, you'll need to model your data for the way your app wants to consume it. See this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) for a great introduction.

Answer (score 0):

This will parse through each node grabbing the currentCity key. If currentCity is `NULLABLE`, I would recommend housing it in a separate node.

```
let ref = // path to users here
ref.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    // Put all of the users into a dictionary
    let postDict = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
    for user in postDict {
        // Set each child of the user as a dictionary
        let data = activity.1 as! [String : AnyObject]

        // Get the specific child
        let currentCity = children["currentCity"] as! String

        // Do something with the data
        print(currentCity)
    }
})
```